# CSS scroll snap choppy/laggy on Chrome desktop

Tags: css, lag, scroll-snap

I've been building this page using scroll-snap and it's working well on Firefox desktop & mobile, as well as Chrome mobile.

But on Chrome desktop (Edge desktop as well) I get very choppy/laggy scroll animation, to the point I don't consider it usable as it is.

I've been looking for a few hours now, to no avail. Any help or lead or idea would be greatly appreciated.

I'm on Windows 10.

---

Here's the SCSS for the snap container and items:

```
.works {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
   scroll-behavior: smooth;
          
   overflow: scroll;
   height: calc(100vh - var(--header-height) - 2vh);
   width: 100vw;
       
   position: absolute;
   top: calc(var(--header-height) + 2vh);
        
   > div {
     margin: 0 auto;
     padding: 2vh 0 0;     
     display: block;
     width: clamp(200px, 100vw, 1280px);
     min-height: 100%;
     z-index: -1; 
       
     background-origin: border-box;
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     background-attachment: fixed;
     background-position: center;
     background-size: auto 100%;
       
     border-radius: .5em;
     border: none;
     border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
     border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
      
     display: grid;
     grid-template-rows: auto 7rem auto;
       
     scroll-snap-align: start;
     scroll-snap-stop: always;    
  }
}
```

And the matching React component:

```
    function Works() {
    
      const contents = worksContents.map( ({ title, year, text, pic }, i)  => {
    
        const styles = {
          backgroundImage: `linear-gradient(transparent, #fdfdfd 75%), url(${pic})`,
        }
    
    
        return (
         
         <div key={ i } style={ styles }> 
    
            <span className='title'> { title } </span>
      
            <span className='year'> { year } </span>
        
            { text }
            
         </div> )
    
        }
    
      )
      
    
      return (
    
          <section className="works">
            {  contents  }
          </section>
    
      )

}

export default Works
```

Comment: Same problem on macOS with Chrome desktop.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? Or is this just chrome's behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

I just wanted to second this question as its affecting me too. Scroll-Snap seems to be completely unusable in desktop chrome at the moment.

I made a codepen to demonstrate the problem:
https://codepen.io/lumakker/pen/poaybJd

html:

```
<div class="testdiv" style="background-color:white">
  <p>compare between scrolling with mousewheel and scrolling with autoscroll (middle mouse button click). Mousewheell scroll-snap is very choppy on chrome desktop.</p>
</div>
<div class="testdiv" style="background-color:black"></div>
<div class="testdiv" style="background-color:green"></div>
<div class="testdiv" style="background-color:red"></div>
```

css:

```
html {
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
  height: 100%
}
body {
  height: 100%
}
.testdiv {
  height: 100%;
  scroll-snap-align: start;
}
```

I hope someone has a solution because I would really like to avoid using a custom scroll-snap js for my website.

Comment: You should not answer a question with another answer.

Comment: He's not asking another question, it's the same problem and he's provided useful details in his pen

Comment: @lumakker did you find a solution?

Comment: @NickW Unfortunately I did not. I am using a custom js scroll snap on chrome as a workaround. I would still strongly prefer using the css one.
Let me know if you find out anything.

Comment: @lumakker will do! I found the same - i'm probably going to resort to gsap for the time being tbh. one thing that makes this worse is that it's *really* quite hard to identify possible solutions, because those solutions are in a sandbox that doesn't suffer from the same issue :/

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Microsoft Edge and experiencing the same laggy performance. I would like to provide some additional information:

1. I have two elements with translateX animations (a marquee) on my
   webpage, and I noticed that removing these elements eliminates the
   lag.
2. Initially, the webpage performs smoothly, but if I minimize the browser for several seconds and then reopen it, the lag appears.
3. Interestingly, after refreshing the page, it becomes smooth again.

It may be related to React's DOM manipulation, but I'm not entirely sure. I believe this issue is associated with the browser's performance, but I'm not certain about the root cause or how to resolve it. I'm eager to hear other answers and perspectives, as they may provide valuable insights.